# How can I create a Bash script that creates multiple files with text, excluding one?

Tags: bash

I need to create  Bash script that generates text files named file001.txt through file050.txt
Of those files, all should have this text inserted "This if file number xxx" (where xxx is the assigned file number), except for file007.txt, which needs to me empty.

This is what I have so far..

```
#!/bin/bash

touch {001..050}.txt

for f in {001..050}

do
    echo This is file number > "$f.txt"

done
```

Not sure where to go from here. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using an `if` statement within the loop, or following the loop by overwriting your chosen file (file007.txt) like `echo > file007.txt`?

Comment: What's the point of the `touch`? What does it do that just redirecting into the file doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` statement can be used to skip an iteration of a loop and go on to the next -- though since you actually *do* want to take an operation on file 7 (creating it), it makes just as much sense to have a conditional:

```
for (( i=1; i<50; i++ )); do
  printf -v filename '%03d.txt' "$i"
  if (( i == 7 )); then
    # create file if it doesn't exist, truncate if it does
    >"$filename"
  else
    echo "This is file number $i" >"$filename"
  fi
done
```

---

A few words about the specific implementation decisions here:

- Using `touch file` is much slower than `> file` (since it starts an external command), and doesn't truncate (so if the file already exists it will retain its contents); your textual description of the problem indicates that you want `007.txt` to be empty, making truncation appropriate.
- Using a C-style `for` loop, ie. `for ((i=0; i<50; i++))`, means you can use a variable for the maximum number; ie. `for ((i=0; i<max; i++))`. You can't do `{001..$max}`, by contrast. However, this *does* need meaning to add zero-padding in a separate step -- hence the `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in {001..050}
do
    if [[ ${f} == "007" ]]
    then
        # creates empty file
        touch "${f}.txt"
    else
        # creates + inserts text into file
        echo "some text/file" > "${f}.txt"
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can costumize the files' name and the text, the key thing is the `${i}`. I tried to be clear, but let us know if you don't understand something.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Looping through 001 to 050
for i in {001..050}
do
    if [ ${i} == 007 ]
    then
        # Create an empty file if the "i" is 007
        echo > "file${i}.txt"
    else
        # Else create a file ("file012.txt" for example)
        # with the text "This is file number 012" 
        echo "This is file number ${i}" > "file${i}.txt"
    fi
done
```